# How to Fastes Remote Connection in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am making a website for PvP servers in PHP language. I have to comply with my own server so that my software does not have w-a-r-e-z. But I have to connect to the client's database with sql remote. (SQL Server 2014).

While the script is running very fast on the local connection, the remote sql connection opens 1-2 minutes late. This, in turn, will not please the customer. I can not imagine if they think you get 500-1000 hits. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear. Please add some code how you are initiation the connection. By the way, a lot of people would implement this different. Encapsulate the DB access with a service and an rest api  - you fetch the data via http/json. This has the advantage that you don't depend on schema changes of the database, you can implement your way of authentication and do a lot more...

Comment: You have probably some networking problem in infrastructure. There is no needed extra work for regulary fast connection to sql database.